# $or query in mongodb - node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to do a query with $or in mongodb...
In Robomongo the query works but in browser it returns nil (via node.js)

in robo mongo I've tried: `db.ocorrencias.find({"$or": [ { "_id":ObjectId("54ff5ed8d094b1e371fba0a7")} ]})`

it works and bring me the JSON

My app.js (it retuns an empty json with the same query)

```
  app.get('/obterOcorrencias',function(req,res){

console.log(req.protocol+":/"+req.get('host'));
   var collection = "ocorrencias";
   var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

   collectionDriver.getCollection(collection, function(error, the_collection) {
        if (error) { 
res.end("<h1>Eerro</h1>");
        }
        else  
     the_collection.find(req.query, function(error,doc) { 
              if (error) 
                res.end(error);
              else {        
                res.status(200).send(doc);    
               }
            });

   });
```

the link:

`http://mysite:3000/obterOcorrencias?query={"$or": [ { "_id":ObjectId("54ff5ed8d094b1e371fba0a7")} ]}`

**EDIT:**

If instead of `the_collection.find(req.query, function(error,doc)` I use `the_collection.find({'$or':{'_id':ObjectId('54ff5ed8d094b1e371fba0a7')}};function(error,doc)` 
it works...but If this string comes from parameters, don't...

Comment: That a string and not an object.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. Because case different from my guess. What does req.query include?

Comment: @user3765109 req.query.query is the 'query' parameter from url

Comment: Actually if you get ` $or:[{ '_id': '54ff5ed8d094b1e371fba0a7' }]` from your `req.query` object MongoDB native drive doesn't know `_id` as an `ObjectId`value. For this reason I use an ODM (Mongoose). When using Mongoose, I create a model to define '_id' is an ObjectId (in fact _id field is defined automatically), 'username' is a string and then Mongoose convert my query parameters automatically proper to my Collection before perform my query. This could be your problem?